# Simplify the radical expression

Tags: arithmetic

> **Simplify the following:**
>   $$\sqrt{48 a^2 b^7}$$

All I have so far is 16  I think i forgot how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{(48 a^ b)^7}$ ?

Comment: close. everything is correct except the variables are a squared and b to the 7th.

Comment: $\sqrt{48 a^2 b^7}$?

Comment: yes! exactly.  can you help me?

Comment: `All I have so far is 16 ` HOW DOES THAT HAPPEN?

Comment: i meant 16*3 ( i have kids, hard to concentrate,lol)

Comment: @Karen Next time post your kids' (or your?) attempt then... You're receiving so many down votes because you didn't show any attempt on what seems to be a homework question. You can get banned from asking questions, you know...

Comment: and it's looking like I might have been on the wrong road any way!!

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't realize that. I'm VERY new to both computers and algebra, really am trying though!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}48&=\underbrace{2\times 2}\times\underbrace{2\times2}\times3\\a^2&=\underbrace{a\times a}\\b^7&=\underbrace{b\times b}\times \underbrace{b\times b}\times \underbrace{b\times b}\times b\end{align}$$

When you take the square root of them:

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{48}&=\underbrace{\sqrt{2\times 2}}_2\times\underbrace{\sqrt{2\times2}}_2\times\sqrt3\\a^2&=\underbrace{\sqrt{a\times a}}_{a}\\b^7&=\underbrace{\sqrt{b\times b}}_{b}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{b\times b}}_{b}\times \underbrace{\sqrt{b\times b}}_{b}\times \sqrt{b}\end{align}$$

So you're left with:

$$4ab^3\sqrt{3b}$$

Note that:
$$(4ab^3)^\frac22\sqrt{3b}=\sqrt{16a^2b^6}\sqrt{3b}=\sqrt{48a^2b^7}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fact that $\sqrt{x\cdot y}=\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt {y}$. For example, 
$$\sqrt{72}=\sqrt{36\cdot 2}=\sqrt{36}\cdot\sqrt{2}=6\sqrt{2}$$
Can you see how this would relate to your example?

Comment: It might also help to remember that $x^m\cdot x^n=x^{m+n}$.

Comment: so on the b to the 7th, it's ok to split that to b^3 and b ^4?

Comment: Sure! But it might be better to split it into $b^6$ and $b$.